# FullCalendar: Month View: Set a minimum size for each day--even if empty

Tags: fullcalendar

Loving fullCalendar.

I have a need to show every day in the month (even if there are no events) with 6 blank lines.  Giving me, if needed, a blank calendar that has enough space in each day that when I print it and give to our volunteers, they can write in each cell.

Comment: Just play with the overall size of the calendar. It's made to be proportionally sized, so just make it as big as you need it.

Comment: That doesn't do it...tried using aspectRatio to achieve what you suggested, and it doesn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: The size of the calendar is controlled by its width when rendered. A calendar with very large cells: http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/8auggxcm/ . How exactly do you want it to look?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Your tip sent me in the right direction.
I have variables giving the reader the ability to choose their own lineheight, font size, # of lines, etc.   I needed to give them the ability to set the HEIGHT parameter as well.  It all works perfectly now. Thank you!